# unable to upgrade 12.10 to subsequent releases

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, updates

I know 12.10 is no longer supported and that transition period ended in May or July 2014. I simply wanted to upgrade to 13.10, and from there on to 14.05 doing the usual 
sudo do-release-upgrade command and everything that comes with it, but it dosen't seem to work. the commandline message I get after a while is

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/source/Sources 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80] 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

Any ideas on what's going on? The menu from software updater is also giving me the message that the repository can no longer be accessed (since 12.10 is not supported anymore).

What are my options?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a fresh install of 14.04 , do not format your root partition and your data in /home will be preserved.

See - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

A fresh install is going to be faster and less problematic then upgrading through 2 unsupported releases (13.04 -> 13.10) and then to 14.04.